# How to send mail to hundreds of receivers?

Tags: php, email

Now i do send emails with this loop:

```
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultat)){
    ...
    sendMail();
}

function sendMail(){
    ...
    mail($to, $subject, $text, $headers);
}
```

But this is not so memory efficient what I can understand. The script should be able to send to over 1000 receivers.

Do you know how to do this in a better way? I want to keep it simple and do not wont to install any framework.

Comment: [Similar question](http://serverfault.com/questions/68357/whats-the-best-way-to-send-bulk-email)

Answer (score 7):

Drop a "note" to a cron job.  In other words, write a file that a cron job picks up and performs the lengthy operation outside of the PHP session.

Of course you can use PHP for the actual script that cron will run :-)

The reason I am suggesting this: you probably don't want to **hold up your PHP session** hanging for too long: delegating to an external process makes (probably) more sense.

Also note that each PHP session is very **often limited in memory**: delegating to an external process might relieve this strain.

Comment: Hm, how do I do that? Have never heard of cron before.

Comment: cron is the Linux job scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

You say you don't want to install a framework, but I don't think PHP's mail is really built for sending out massive amounts of email quickly and efficiently.  I would try Pear's [Mail_Queue](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Queue/) or [Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail).

Answer (score 1):

Look into integrating with list manager software such as Majordomo.  It's easy to do an adequate job broadcasting emails.  It's hard to do a great job, and these people have put a lot of blood sweat and tears into making this work well.

Just be mindful that your recipients are expecting the email, or you'll end up getting yourself put on realtime spam blacklists, and possibly have your host kick you off their network.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is probably the best for such operations.

With AJAX, you can call a small *.php-File containing just the function to send an email to the next user. That is called every bunch of seconds and you're done.

Of course, if you don't like client-scripting, such operations become quite difficult to manage with PHP.

Comment: AJAX is not a magic potion, nor is it a solution for everything - you now have the exact same problem, distributed between the client and server, plus the overhead of thousands of requests (-> huge memory leaks in certain browsIErs). The fact that you shifted the loop to run in the browser doesn't mean the loop disappeared. Passing the buck != solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can approach this issue, MightyE idea of working with a mailing list manager is probably the "Right Thing (tm)" to do - set up a mailing list using Listman, Sympa, Majordomo or one of the other hundreds of mailing list managers. Its often easy to manage it from your PHP script and then you send one email to the mailing list address and let the manager do the rest.

That being said, this solution requires some non-trivial setup, and has the serious short coming of it being very difficult to implement when you need to generate the target emails dynamically (i.e. each email is sent to a different subset of email addresses).

Another, simpler way is to use a twist on justastefan's answer (which is a shame it was so down-voted): it has serious problems but can be made to work.

What you need to do, is to make sure that your PHP script's `mail()` routine delivers to a local MTA. This is the default installation on Linux/BSD servers. Also make sure you use a good MTA such as `postfix` or `exim`. Then when you want to send the mass email, create a list of BCC headers for the sending:

```
$bcc = array();
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultat)){
    $bcc[] = "Bcc: {$data['email']}";
}
sendMail($bcc);

function sendMail($extraheaders){
    ...
    mail($to, $subject, $text, array_merge($headers, $extraheaders));
}
```

This is a fairly efficient way - the BCC headers are quite compact and are only parsed by the local MTA service that `mail()` delivers to directly.

There are a few caveats that you need to take care of, otherwise the recipients' mail servers will likely flag your emails as "spam":

1. Always make sure you have a valid 'To' address that can accept (and possibly silently ignore) the emails - each email will also be sent there. This 'To' address should look legitimate.
2. Make sure to add a "Reply-To" header with an email address to make it easy for recipients to reply to you.
3. Make sure to set a valid "Return-Path" header with a valid email address that can accept email bounces - a missing or invalid "Return-Path" is the single most likely reason for automated emails failing.

Answer (score -4):

```
$to='user1@asdf.com;user2@asdf.com;user3@asd.fi;...';
```

Comment: this is a horrible way to do it, not only will the e-mail end up enormous in size with all of those addresses, you're exposing everyone's addresses too!

Comment: I don't want all the email-addresses to be visible for everyone.

Comment: bcc? that'll strip off the addresses in the first MTA (mails won't be large, you won't display addresses, and the scheduling is done by your MTA). Only drawback is that the addressee won't see his email in the to:-field

Comment: Missing the address in the To field will increase your chances of getting flagged as spam for many email providers.

Comment: Sound not to bad. What's MTA?

Comment: what??.. that answer stole all my points to do things like judging etc... ill go quit :-/